# Calling a method defined in a protocol on a class included with forward declaration

Tags: objective-c, protocols, forward-declaration

Is there a way to tell the compiler that a non-imported class (i.e. forward declaration) adheres to a protocol?

In the example below I want to call a method `foo` on the class `ForwardClass`. The class adheres to the `MyProtocol` protocol, but the compiler won't know that since forward declaration is used.

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

+ (void) foo;

@end


@class ForwardClass; // <-- Forward declaration

@implementation MyClass

- (void) bar
{
    [ForwardClass foo]; // <-- This doesn't work!
}
```

What I was hoping for was to either apply the protocol while declaring the class like so:

```
@class ForwardClass <MyProtocol>
```

or to somehow use the protocol while calling the method like so:

```
[ForwardClass<MyProtocol> foo];
```

This is not really a big issue since I could just import the class straight away, but it would be nice if it worked since I would only have to import the protocol, and not the whole class.

Comment: To start with, your protocol declares instance method, not class method.

Comment: @Kreiri My bad, should've been a class method of course. Have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Forward declarations are for situations where you need to know the the class type but don't need to know about its specific implementation (properties and methods for example).  In your case you do care about the methods it implements so you need to bring in the header for for ForwardClass.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
Class x = NSClassFromString(@"ForwardClass");
[x foo];
```

but it is not as pretty